# Layout dynamic number of sprites in a circle

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to create a fixed size circle that will have a varying number (between 6 - 12) of rectangle sprites positioned on it.  I've read about a cocos2d function called drawCircle which is great for displaying a circle.  I'd like to display a circle, but I'd also like to include the rectangle sprites on top of it, spaced evenly depending on the number of sprites.
Is there a function that would layout the rectangle sprites in a circle?

[image: Example of circle with rectangle sprites.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a little bit of trigonometry in your future! Perhaps draw the circle using a drawing function, and then compute points for the center of each box?

You'll need to know the radius of your circle, obviously, but from there it should be pretty simple. It looks like you want to place them at 45 degree angles. So the first box would be placed at point `(radius, 0)`, the second at `(radius*cos(45), radius*sin(45))`, third at `(0, radius)`, etc.

The above math is assuming standard counter-clockwise rotation from 0-360 degrees. You can also use radians - you would then compute all these points with `theta = 0, pi/4, pi/2, 3pi/4, pi, 5pi/4, 3pi/2, and 7pi/4`

Basically is the circle center is `x0, y0`, your calculated points will be `(x0 + radius*cos(theta), y0 + radius*sin(theta))`

Should be fairly simple math at play there :)

Comment: Thanks bgoers, I'll give those functions a try.  ;)

Comment: I've tried those functions.  I'm able to get a circle to appear, but the rectangle I'm drawing isn't displaying anywhere near where I'd expect it to.  If I set it's position to be the same as the circle, I would expect it to end up in the center of the circle, but it's off the screen.

Comment: You might be mixing node spaces at that point. What I described was assuming that both the circle and rectangles are in the same node space (i.e. both are in the same layer or relative to the same node, etc.)